# jquery-chosen multiple attribute allowing tag order same as list order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-chosen

In my html i'm using chosen jquery(1.6.2) from [here](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).
I'm facing problem while multiple selection, order of the selected tags are sorting in same order as they are in drop-down list.
I want the selected order rather than order by list.

```
    <select class="chosen-select" chosen multiple>
    </select>
```

but still order sorting is getting done. I want to handle the order please help.

Comment: TIP:add the list of items to array  when select change.. then u can send in the order from the array

Comment: Thank you but it did not work, it would be better to stop looping the selected items as per index. Can i make it stop looping?

Comment: below is the html which returns the order of multiselect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Get Multiple Selected Option Value</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr=[];
var selected;
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("select.country").click(function(){ 
   var latestSelected;
    if (selected) {
        var currentOptionsValue = $(this).val();
        latestSelected = currentOptionsValue.filter(function(element) {
        return selected.indexOf(element) < 0;
  });
}
if(!selected){
arr.push($(this).val());
}
else{
 arr.push(latestSelected);
}
selected = $(this).val();
//console.log( "latest selected option : " + latestSelected);
    });

});
function getValues(){

        alert(arr.join(','));
    }   
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>Country:</label>
        <select class="country" multiple="multiple" size="5">
            <option>United States</option>
            <option>India</option>
            <option>United Kingdom</option>
            <option>Brazil</option>
            <option>Germany</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" onclick="getValues();">Get Values</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```